# Cannot read property ‘options’ of undefined in model.update method

Tags: sequelize.js

I’m getting the error: **Cannot read property ‘options’ of undefined**

This is the code:

```
const x = await Foo.update( {name: 'Baz'},
      { where: { id: '707169f6-b8e6-49f0-9227-26bed30dd828' } }
    );
```

The options param is clearly defined with the where clause included

**Note: This same block of code works for another model Baz**

Why is this happening?

Comment: Please show stacktrace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my Foo model was a default scope which eager loaded the associations and excluded certain fields. The conversion of that default scope to a named scope solved the issue.